# Redis get command unpredictable result in runtime

Tags: java, redis

I have a small program which establishes web socket connection with crypto exchange, receive data and save it with `set` Redis command.

**Code**

```
//get Redis connection
    RedisAsyncCommands<String, String> redis = TRedis.getRedis();
    String symbol = "AGIETH";
    Session session = null;
    try {
        //Open websocket connection. 
        session = (new 
  BinanceApi()).websocketTrades(BinanceSymbol.valueOf(symbol), new BinanceWebSocketAdapterAggTrades() {
            @Override
            public void onMessage(BinanceEventAggTrade message) {
                double closeOrderBuy = 0;
                double closeOrderSell = 0;
                //check if we  saved order information before and if yes get data from Redis
                try {
                    if(redis.get(symbol+"Buy").get()!=null )
                    {
                        closeOrderBuy = Double.valueOf(redis.get(symbol+"Buy").get());
                    }
                    if( redis.get(symbol+"Sell").get()!=null)
                    {
                        closeOrderSell = Double.valueOf(redis.get(symbol+"Sell").get());
                    }

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // get current value from exchange
                double currentCloseOrder = message.getPrice().multiply(message.getQuantity()).doubleValue();

                // rewrite data in Redis
                if(message.isMaker()) {
                    closeOrderBuy = currentCloseOrder + closeOrderBuy;
                    redis.set(symbol + "Buy",String.valueOf(closeOrderBuy));
                }
                else {
                    closeOrderSell = currentCloseOrder + closeOrderSell;
                    redis.set(symbol + "Sell",String.valueOf(closeOrderSell));
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (BinanceApiException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        session.close();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
//check what we write
    try {
        System.out.println(symbol + redis.get(symbol + "Buy").get() + "  " + redis.get(symbol + "Sell").get());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This is part of console output for AGIETH pair:

```
18:01:00.197 [lettuce-nioEventLoop-4-1] DEBUG io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler - [channel=0x6893917d, /127.0.0.1:64152 -> localhost/127.0.0.1:6379, chid=0x1] write(ctx, AsyncCommand [type=GET, output=ValueOutput [output=null, error='null'], commandType=io.lettuce.core.protocol.Command], promise)
18:01:00.197 [lettuce-nioEventLoop-4-1] DEBUG io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandEncoder - [channel=0x6893917d, /127.0.0.1:64152 -> localhost/127.0.0.1:6379] writing command AsyncCommand [type=GET, output=ValueOutput [output=null, error='null'], commandType=io.lettuce.core.protocol.Command]  
18:01:00.197 [lettuce-nioEventLoop-4-1] DEBUG io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler - [channel=0x6893917d, /127.0.0.1:64152 -> localhost/127.0.0.1:6379, chid=0x1] Received: 5 bytes, 1 commands in the stack  
18:01:00.197 [lettuce-nioEventLoop-4-1] DEBUG io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler - [channel=0x6893917d, /127.0.0.1:64152 -> localhost/127.0.0.1:6379, chid=0x1] Stack contains: 1 commands
18:01:00.197 [lettuce-nioEventLoop-4-1] DEBUG io.lettuce.core.protocol.RedisStateMachine - Decode AsyncCommand [type=GET, output=ValueOutput [output=null, error='null'], commandType=io.lettuce.core.protocol.Command]  
18:01:00.197 [lettuce-nioEventLoop-4-1] DEBUG io.lettuce.core.protocol.RedisStateMachine - Decoded AsyncCommand [type=GET, output=ValueOutput [output=null, error='null'], commandType=io.lettuce.core.protocol.Command], empty stack: true  
***AGIETH 0.045027  null***
```

**Output for AGIBTC pair**

```
13:51:02.646 [lettuce-nioEventLoop-4-1] DEBUG io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler - [channel=0xc565134b, /127.0.0.1:54361 -> localhost/127.0.0.1:6379, chid=0x1] write(ctx, AsyncCommand [type=GET, output=ValueOutput [output=null, error='null'], commandType=io.lettuce.core.protocol.Command], promise)
13:51:02.646 [lettuce-nioEventLoop-4-1] DEBUG io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandEncoder - [channel=0xc565134b, /127.0.0.1:54361 -> localhost/127.0.0.1:6379] writing command AsyncCommand [type=GET, output=ValueOutput [output=null, error='null'], commandType=io.lettuce.core.protocol.Command]
13:51:02.646 [lettuce-nioEventLoop-4-1] DEBUG io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler - [channel=0xc565134b, /127.0.0.1:54361 -> localhost/127.0.0.1:6379, chid=0x1] Received: 25 bytes, 1 commands in the stack
13:51:02.646 [lettuce-nioEventLoop-4-1] DEBUG io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler - [channel=0xc565134b, /127.0.0.1:54361 -> localhost/127.0.0.1:6379, chid=0x1] Stack contains: 1 commands
13:51:02.646 [lettuce-nioEventLoop-4-1] DEBUG io.lettuce.core.protocol.RedisStateMachine - Decode AsyncCommand [type=GET, output=ValueOutput [output=null, error='null'], commandType=io.lettuce.core.protocol.Command]
13:51:02.646 [lettuce-nioEventLoop-4-1] DEBUG io.lettuce.core.protocol.RedisStateMachine - Decoded AsyncCommand [type=GET, output=ValueOutput [output=0.5475444299999999, error='null'], commandType=io.lettuce.core.protocol.Command], empty stack: true  
**AGIBTC 0.20769342999999998  0.5475444299999999**
```

I receive Null for some pairs, but exchange provides this information. I don't understand if it's a Redis problem, or if the logic of my program is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

I see two problems with your code:

1. You use Redis async API but do not wait properly for set() operation to complete. RedisAsyncCommands.set returns RedisFuture. Before calling get() you must ensure that future is completed.
2. You wait 10 seconds for trade event from BinanceApi. But some currency pairs may have few trades so 10 seconds is just not enough.

I've slightly modified your code by adding proper waiting conditions and all seems to work fine:

```
//get Redis connection
    RedisClient client = RedisClient.create("redis://localhost");
    StatefulRedisConnection<String, String> connection = client.connect();
    RedisAsyncCommands<String, String> redis = connection.async();
    String symbol = "AGIETH";
    Session session = null;
    CompletableFuture<String> cfBuy = new CompletableFuture<>();
    CompletableFuture<String> cfSell = new CompletableFuture<>();
    try {
        //Open websocket connection. 
        session = (new
            BinanceApi()).websocketTrades(BinanceSymbol.valueOf(symbol), new BinanceWebSocketAdapterAggTrades() {
            @Override
            public void onMessage(BinanceEventAggTrade message) {
                double closeOrderBuy = 0;
                double closeOrderSell = 0;
                //check if we  saved order information before and if yes get data from Redis
                try {
                    if(redis.get(symbol+"Buy").get()!=null )
                    {
                        closeOrderBuy = Double.valueOf(redis.get(symbol+"Buy").get());
                    }
                    if( redis.get(symbol+"Sell").get()!=null)
                    {
                        closeOrderSell = Double.valueOf(redis.get(symbol+"Sell").get());
                    }

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // get current value from exchange
                double currentCloseOrder = message.getPrice().multiply(message.getQuantity()).doubleValue();

                // rewrite data in Redis
                if(message.isMaker()) {
                    closeOrderBuy = currentCloseOrder + closeOrderBuy;
                    redis.set(symbol + "Buy",String.valueOf(closeOrderBuy)).thenAccept(cfBuy::complete);
                }
                else {
                    closeOrderSell = currentCloseOrder + closeOrderSell;
                    redis.set(symbol + "Sell",String.valueOf(closeOrderSell)).thenAccept(cfSell::complete);
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (BinanceApiException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        System.out.println("Futures completed: " + cfBuy.get() + " " + cfSell.get());
        session.close();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //check what we write
    try {
        System.out.println(symbol + redis.get(symbol + "Buy").get() + "  " + redis.get(symbol + "Sell").get());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Output:

```
Futures completed: OK OK
AGIETH0.06922798  0.08610368
```